# Does the Rancher profession bonus apply to proccessed animal products?

Tags: stardew-valley

At Level 5 Farming, I'm faced with a choice of Rancher or Tiller for a profession.

The Rancher bonus of 20% is appealing to me, but right now all my animal products get processed (cooking, mayonnaise, etc). As far as I can tell, the game treats these items as "Cooking" or "Artisan" items, not animal products.

So at this point I'm unsure if the Rancher bonus will be very useful to me. Will a Rancher bonus apply to processed items like Mayonnaise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to posts in [this thread](http://steamcommunity.com/app/413150/discussions/0/405692758719584614/), Artisan products are counted as animal products and will benefit from the Rancher perk, as of February 2016.

> the game was just updated so that artisaned goods now receive the bonus from rancher.

This update is mentioned in [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/StardewValley/comments/49sj51/suggestion_make_mayonnaise_and_cheese_into_animal/), as well and includes the relevant patch notes:

> Interestingly, Patch 1.03 (from a while back, February 28th) lists...
>
> "The price of mayonnaise and other artisan animal products now increased by the rancher profession."